# Set featured image via post content programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress

I was trying to add featured image from post content. My idea is to set the first image of the content as featured image of the post.

I wrote this in my *funtions.php*

```
    add_action('publish_post', 'auto_featured_image_publish_post');
         function auto_featured_image_publish_post($post, $post_id) {
           $thumnail_id = //something I need help with
           set_post_thumbnail( $post, $thumbnail_id );
         }
```

This is just an idea how I want to do this.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this url

https://www.gavick.com/blog/wordpress-quick-tip-4-automatically-set-the-first-post-image-as-a-featured-image

OR you can use this code to get the url of the first image from any HTML code

```
<?php
$postcontent = "";
preg_match('/<img.+src=[\'"](?P<src>.+?)[\'"].*>/i', $postcontent, $image);
// you can use the exist pattern or use this
// '/< *img[^>]*src *= *["\']?([^"\']*)/i'
echo $image['src'];
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick help.
I think I need to input the image attachment id in order to make it work properly. Do you have any idea on it ? The thumbnail_id has to be integer. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail

Comment: check this url https://www.gavick.com/blog/wordpress-quick-tip-4-automatically-set-the-first-post-image-as-a-featured-image

Comment: Thank you Mostafa Bhai. You saved my day :)